# Why is Drupal writing to root and not sites/default/files?

Tags: drupal, iis-7, windows-7, wimp

I'm using Drupal 6.14 on Win7. Everything seems to work except files that should be written to sites/default/files are trying to be written to /. The site was moved from a linux installation, which is writing the files correctly. I have setup a web.config w/ the rewrite rules for drupal. Not sure what or where else I should check. Thanks for any help.

```
<rule name="Drupal Clean URLs" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?q={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check what the file system path is set to in `/admin/settings/file-system`. (I'd guess it's empty for some reason.)

Comment: Thanks! It was the temporary directory setting on the /admin/settings/file-system page. Changed to C:\windows\temp.

Comment: I've since found out c:\windows\temp is not a good place due to permissions issues. Using a directory in the site seems to work best, like: [siteroot]\sites\default\files\temp